# WPF: Create a custom control without rewriting the ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, templates, custom-controls

Hey, I am creating a Custom Control i WPF inheriting from the ListView. However, I want it to look exactly as the already existing ListView.

Is there a way To use the default ListView Template in a Custom Control without rewriting it in xaml? I do have a Generic.xaml file with the new control added, but I should no need to rewrite the template code.

Thanks

EDIT: I also want to keep it as DRY as possible without repeating (making a mess) the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you subclass the ListView, them your subclassed control will use the ListView Template. That's it! You do not have to do anything!

The Template used by a control is defined by its DefaultStyleKey dependency property. If you want to change the template of your control, set this property as follows:

```
  DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyControl),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));
```

However, if you do not set this property, it will use the value set by the superclass.

I think the problem is that you have used "Add New Item" => "Custom Control" to create you control then changed the class it extends. Instead of doing this, just add a new C# class and extend ListView.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}" BasedOn={StaticResource {x:Type ListView}}" />
```